# Error when trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

hi i am trying to show the value of name which is stored in database but i am getting this error can anyone please guide me how can i rectify my error .

```
  <form action="Store-data" method="POST">
         @csrf
         <div class="form-group my-2">

         <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{ $Task ->name }}"> 
     <div class="form-group my-2">
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"  value="{{ $Task ->email }}" > 
     <div class="form-group my-2 text-center">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add user</button>

     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
     </form>
```

here is my edit controller

```
 public function edit($Taskid)
    {
        //

        $Edit= Superior::find($Taskid);

        return view('Myview.edit')->with('Task','$Edit');


    }
```

here is my route for edit

```
Route::get('Superior/{Task}/edit','SuperiorController@edit');
```

i am using Task as a key but it is giving me an error 
i also tried but didn't work

```
{{$Task['name']}}
```

Comment: make sure `$Edit= Superior::find($Taskid);` is an object, try `findOrFail`.

Comment: I think you are missing `Request` `public function edit(Request $Request, $Taskid){//}`

Comment: i did tred as u said  $Edit= Superior::findorFail($Taskid); but it didn't help the only problem that i am facing in my page is when i try to print my value using  {{$Task->name}} this

Comment: public function edit(Request $Request, $Taskid)  @Rahul i tried this it still gives the error syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Try mine @ZaeemSyed :)

Comment: nope it didn't helped khalid khan sab

Comment: @ZaeemSyed Any error ? let me know. actually you have problem in your route and moreover you are using Capitalize naming convention which doesn't help in code readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `'` that wraps `$Edit`.

```
return view('Myview.edit')->with('Task', $Edit);
```

Comment: return view('Myview.edit')->with('Task',$Edit); did that error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

**Form Code**

```
<form action="Store-data" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group my-2">
        <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{isset($Edit) ? $Edit->name : '' }}"> 
        <div class="form-group my-2">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"  value="{{ isset($Edit) ? $Edit->email : '' }}"> 
            <div class="form-group my-2 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add user</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('Superior/edit/{id}','SuperiorController@edit');
```

**Controller Code**

```
public function edit($id){
    $Edit= Superior::find($id);
    return view('Myview.edit',compact('Edit'));
}
```

Hopefully it'll solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create function like this. if `Taskid` in your database column.

```
public function edit(Request $Request, $Taskid)
{
    //

    $Edit= Superior::where('Taskid', $Taskid)->first();

    return view('Myview.edit', compact(Edit));

}
```

In your html it will like this

```
{{ $Edit->name }}
```

In your Route

```
Route::get('Superior/{Taskid}/edit','SuperiorController@edit');
```